# How to find the Galois group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2})$. I'm asked to find the galois group
$G(K/\mathbb{Q})$. Is the following argumentation sufficient or excessive?

Since $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$ and $i\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ we know that the cycles (correct word?) in $G(K/\mathbb{Q})$ must permute the roots, ie $\sqrt{2} \to -\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{3} \to -i\sqrt{3}$.

And so the cycles (correct word?) in $G(K/\mathbb{Q})$ are:

$\sigma_0 = id$

$\sigma_1 = \sqrt{2}\to\ -\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{3}\to\ i\sqrt{3}$

$\sigma_2 = \sqrt{2}\to\ \sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{3}\to\ -i\sqrt{3}$

$\sigma_3 = \sigma_2\sigma_1=
 \sqrt{2}\to\ -\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{3}\to\ -i\sqrt{3}$

And so $G(K/\mathbb{Q}) =\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: I might suggest "elements of" instead of "cycles in" which seems to be used more frequently in terms of permutation groups or in conjunction with an order, e.g. a $3$-cycle.  How is it you seem to know that the Galois group has order $4$?  Why not more?

Comment: I believe you should write the basis of K and describe the action on the basis that each possible automorphism would have, to determine the order of the group first.

Comment: @sharding4 That's the only possible permutations of those 4 roots ($\pm i\sqrt{3}$ can't go to $\pm\sqrt{2}$ and vice versa).

Comment: I believe klorzan and I are both trying to get at the same thing which is that you should pin down $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$, because that will equal $|Gal(K/Q)|$.

Comment: Your  arguments are absolutely sufficient, but it would be better to say permutations instead of cycles, even though the sigmas are some of them

Comment: @sharding4 because this looks like a finite normal extension, so K/Q is a splitting field, and separable

Comment: Perhaps it's just too picky, but I would note that $[K:Q]=4$ and $1,\sqrt 2, i \sqrt 3,\, \text{ and } i\sqrt 6$ form a basis.  Then when you demonstrate that you have 4 distinct $Q$-autmorphisms, it's clear those make up the Galois group (and aren't just part of the group).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WL5iWcZ.jpg